# Is c++ final non-virtual class reinterpreted as array safe for use?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, reinterpret-cast

I've got a non-virtual final class that declares only same type fields.

```
struct Vector3 final
{
    float X, Y, Z;
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z) : X(x), Y(y), Z(z)
    {

    }

    float Sum()
    {
        return X + Y + Z;
    }
};
```

Is it safe to reinterpret pointer to instance of this class to array of floats?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Vector3 v(10, 20, 30);
    Vector3 *pV = &v;
    float *ff = reinterpret_cast<float*>(pV);

    std::cout << ff[0] << std::endl << ff[1] << std::endl << ff[2] << std::endl;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure because of the possibility of padding being added (otherwise I'd post an answer). Why not overload `operator[]` if you want this behavior? It'd certainly make your call sites cleaner.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Yup, that's the right solution.

Comment: Is there a source of internal padding other than 9.2/14? It would seem to have no effect on a standard-layout class containing members of a single type: "Implementation alignment requirements might
cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for
space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1)." I can find no other sources of padding in C++11, but it's not exactly a no-padding guarantee either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe, but beware [breaking strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)!

In C++11 jargon your struct is [Standard Layout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType), hence it's safe to cast it via `reinterpret_cast` to its first member:

> **§ 9.2.20 Class members [class.mem]**
>
> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa.

The subsequent floats are then contiguous in memory, just like an array.

---

Why dont you provide an `operator[]`?

Comment: Tested it and put a static_assert

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't -- there may be padding between the data members.

Comment: Also Google "strict aliasing". He'd need to access via a `char*` or other compiler specific non-aliased typed. GCC offers `__attribute__((__may_alias__))` for instance.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Yup, and also some of the `((packed))` attributes.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG (I **do** know what strict aliasing is.)

Comment: The only mention of padding in C++11 is in 9.2/14: "Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).". None of the cited reasons for adding  padding would apply to a standard-layout struct whose members all have the same type.

Comment: @Casey Sorry, but I don't see how the class being standard-layout changes the situation. All I can find about pointer conversion and aliasing etc. in the standard is the usual "pointer to struct points to its initial member" clause (and variations thereof, including the statements about common initial sequences of structures). Furthermore, 9.2.20 asserts that: "[Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. -- end note]".

Comment: 9.2/14 cites 2 reasons for an implementation to allocate members discontiguously: (1) alignment, which doesn't make sense with same-type members, (2) "space for managing virtual functions/base classes" which a standard-layout class cannot have. I propose that the standard implicitly forbids padding between the members of the subject `struct`.

Comment: @Casey Arguably, it may or may not make sense. Nevertheless, it can be there.

Comment: @H2CO3 Do you suggest that `float` may have more stringent alignment requirements when used as a member of a struct than when used in an array? 3.11/2 does state "The
alignment required for a type might be different when it is used as the type of a complete object and when
it is used as the type of a subobject.", but according to 1.8/2 array elements and structure members are both subobjects. So if `Vector3::X` is properly aligned, the standard does not give the impementation license to insert padding before `Vector3::Y`.

Comment: @Casey "Different" may mean both "higher" or "lower" (unless it is explicitly specified which alignment should be which), but I don't see how the next assertion is relevant anyway. Yes, the members are definitely subobjects. And they may have different alignment requirements than those of a complete object. But why does this mean that there can't be padding between them? I think we'll need to discuss this issue more (I'll try to find something relevant on the topic, perhaps comp.lang.c++ could help us too?)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in portable C++, no; because the system (compiler, runtime, etc) is free to order and space struct/class members as it pleases. For example, to align members on CPU word boundaries.

If you control the compiler used to build the project you *can* get away with it. If you're using VC you'll need to use `#pragma pack`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx

Comment: Not free to order them entirely (it can put publics before privates, etc, but not do random shuffles) but you're correct about the padding issue.